# Zariski closure of orbits of real groups on complex flag manifolds

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, reductive-groups, real-algebraic-geometry

Let $G$ be a complex reductive algebraic group defined over $\mathbb R$, and $G_0$ its real points. Then the orbits of $G_0$ on $G/B$ need not be real algebraic subvarieties. Take $G=SL_2(\mathbb C)$, $G_0 = SL_2(\mathbb R)$, where the orbits are the equator $\mathbb{RP}^1$ and the two open hemispheres. But if we took $GL_2$ instead of $SL_2$ the two hemispheres would be in one orbit.

> For which $G_0$ can I think of this as a real algebraic action? In particular, I would have to identify the complex manifold $G/B$ as the real points of something else.

Matsuki duality lets one correspond the $G_0$-orbits with $K$-orbits, where $K$ is the complexification of a maximal compact subgroup of $G_0$. *Those* are complex algebraic. Springer defines a map $\varphi: KgB \mapsto \theta(gB)gB \in B\backslash G/B \cong W$, where $\theta$ is the involution of $G$ fixing $K$.

In particular, the open $G_0$-orbits correspond to the closed $K$-orbits, which are those that map to $1$.

> Assuming the first question, is the Zariski closure of a $G_0$-orbit the union of the orbits with the same value of $\varphi$?

In general, I've found it more annoying to deal with the $K$-orbits than their $\varphi$-values, and I'm wondering if this would help motivate gluing them together (at the cost of switching from complex to real algebraic geometry).

Of course there is an immense literature on Matsuki duality, so I am hoping for a reference.

Comment: You use "real algebraic subvariety" and "real algebraic action" with non-standard meaning; please define your intent with such terms. If $H$ is a split connected reductive $\mathbf{R}$-group (e.g. SL$_2$), $X={\rm{Bor}}_{H/\mathbf{R}}$ is the $\mathbf{R}$-variety of Borel subgroups, and $x\in X(\mathbf{R})$ then $H$ acts on the Weil restriction $X':={\rm{R}}_{\mathbf{C}/\mathbf{R}}(X_{\mathbf{C}})$ with orbit through $x$ exactly $H/B_x\subset X'$ and $(H/B_x)(\mathbf{R})=H(\mathbf{R})/B_x(\mathbf{R})$ by Hilbert 90. So it *is*  $\mathbf{R}$-points of something $\mathbf{R}$-algebraic in $X'$.

Comment: I'm having trouble unpacking your description. What are the _complex_ points of the space you suggest I find containing $G_{\mathbb C}/B_{\mathbb C}$ as the $\mathbb R$-points?

Comment: Unraveling definition, the set of $\mathbf{C}$-points of ${\rm{R}}_{\mathbf{C}/\mathbf{R}}(X_{\mathbf{C}})$ is $X(\mathbf{C}\otimes_{\mathbf{R}}\mathbf{C}) = X(\mathbf{C})\timesX(\mathbf{C})$ via the $\mathbf{C}$-algebra isomorphism $\mathbf{C}\otimes_{\mathbf{R}}\mathbf{C}=\mathbf{C} \times\mathbf{C}$ via $a\otimes b\mapsto (ab,a\overline{b})$. If you replace $X_{\mathbf{C}}$ with a general affine algebraic $\mathbf{C}$-scheme $Z$ inside the Weil restriction you get $Z(\mathbf{C})\times \overline{Z}(\mathbf{C})$ where $\overline{Z}$ is the twist of $Z$ by complex conjugation on $\mathbf{C}$.